# Multiples Connections to Oracle - Multi Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle

I have a console application that I must *generally speaking* check the entire base to do *stuffs*...

To do so, I am using `Tasks` like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var dateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-35);
        var dateEnd = DateTime.Now;

        var taskList = new List<Task>();

        while (dateStart > dateEnd ? dateStart >= dateEnd : dateStart <= dateEnd)
        {
            var d = dateStart.Date;
            var dispositivesBll = new DispositivesBll();
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                                        {
                                           dispositivesBll.Foo(d);
                                        }).ContinueWith(
                                            x => dispositivesBll.Dispose())
                               .ContinueWith(x => GC.Collect()));

            var dispositivesBllNew = new DispositivesBll();
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                                        {
                                            dispositivesBllNew.Boo(d);
                                        }).ContinueWith(
                                            x =>
                                            dispositivesBllNew.Dispose())
                               .ContinueWith(x => GC.Collect()));

            if (taskList.Count >= 2 * 5)
            {
                Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
                taskList.Clear();
            }
            dateStart = dateStart > dateEnd ? dateStart.AddDays(-1) : dateStart.AddDays(1);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

So Basically I want to run *10 days* at once as you may noticed at `if (taskList.Count >= 2 * 5)` but the problem is that my `Foo` and `Boo` methods have multiples connection to one Oracle Database.

```
public class DispositivesBll : IDisposable 
{
    private readonly OracleDal _oracleDal = new OracleDal();

    public void Foo(DateTime data)
    {

        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
                     {
                         _listSuccess = _oracleDal.GetSuccessList();
                     });

        var t2 =
            Task.Run(() =>
                         {
                             listFailure = _oracleDal.GetFailureList();
                         });

        t1.Wait();
        t2.Wait();

        foreach (var success in _listSuccess)
        {
            //Some logic to insert objects into a "mergeList"
        }

        if (mergeList.Any())
            Task.Run(() => _oracleDal.MergeList(mergeList)).Wait();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_hash != null)
            _hash.Clear();
        _hash = null;

    }
}
```

and my Merge Method:

```
    public void MergeList(List<MyObject> mergeList)
    {
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            using (var oCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"
                MERGE INTO MyTable dgn 
                USING (select id from another_table where field = :xpe) d ON ( TO_CHAR(dateHappen, 'DDMMYYYY') = {0} and id = :xId) WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                    UPDATE SET OK = :xOk, dateHappen = SYSDATE
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                    INSERT (fields....) 
                    VALUES (values...)");
                oCommand.BindByName = true;
                oCommand.ArrayBindCount = mergeList.Count;



                oCommand.Parameters.Add(":xId", OracleDbType.Int32,
                                        mergeList.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Id)).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);

                oCommand.Parameters.Add(":xPe", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                                        mergeList.Select(c => Convert.ToString(c.Xpe)).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);


                oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is: For each "day" it tooks about 2 hours to process everything... and we have a daily plan to backup our database causing the database to stop about 10 minutes... so it would cause a lock in my process...

So what I do? I stop manually this process and start it again avoiding the dates already executed. BUT if I have 20 connections opened, they would stayed that way... So I have to kill those sessions everytime... Is there a way to force all connections to dispose?

**EDIT:**

`MyTable` has 50 mi rows.... composed by `ID | STATE | DATE`... basically I have to cross those STATES with their DATES...
So the big delay it's on the database... It's kinda a known issue that we have to refactor the entire database model.... and we are going to do it soon...

But anyways, despite the process time, if I can just manage (or force) the connection kill, it would be fine...

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the majority of the 'two hours per day' processing time happening? Is it on the database side, or the application side? Is this something that might be better if you ran it more frequently with smaller batches? This may not be a case where there is a simple fix; it might require a redesign after analysis of the entire process.

Comment: A "day" merge process should not be taking anywhere near 2 hours to run; it should be running in a few minutes or less even on database tables with millions of rows.  Can you give us a rough idea of how many rows are in the table `MyTable`, and how many in `another_table` -- and it is also worrisome that your design is set up to manually kill and restart the process.  Also, your database should be in archivelog mode with appropriate RMAN backups so you don't have to do a database export daily.

Comment: The majority it's on the database side, for sure.. There is one same implementation (without tasks) that tooks 4 hours per day.. and I managed to do in 2 hours... but I really need something to control all connections.... I've edited the question with some info.... `MyTable` and `another_table` have more than 50 mi rows each one.... so its pretty big. And I have to join each record with other big tables...sometimes the join occurs with VARCHAR2(15) values.... so its pretty bad the model...

Comment: Who told you Oracle has to be stopped to do the backups? Does RMAN not work? Is your database not in archivelog mode? Are you guys running cold backups?

Comment: @MSStp I dunno about that... that's IBM's job... I mean i'm not responsable for database backup... anyways the database stops by some reason (I assume they are doing backup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in order kill a session, you would need to involve a DBA, which if you do several times a week, would not make for a good friendship!  As myself and others pointed out, a database should not need to be brought down for a backup (except for a cold backup), or for even a export, but if you have these long merge processes a consistent export would take quite a while.  So first step is to educate (nicely) the DBAs on having the database in archivelog mode, and have RMAN manage online backups.

Second, you need to improve the merge criteria so that the merging columns are indexed.  It could well be that `dateHappen` is indexed, but since you are invoking a function on it in the merge criteria, that index cannot be used unless a function-based index is created.  I am referring to the

```
TO_CHAR(dateHappen, 'DDMMYYYY') = {0}
```

specifically; and in general,

```
USING (select id from another_table where field = :xpe) d 
ON ( TO_CHAR(dateHappen, 'DDMMYYYY') = {0} and id = :xId)
```

You should check to see if `id` and `field` on `another_table` is indexed, and create a function-based index on dateHappen:

```
create index i_date_string on whatever_table (TO_CHAR(dateHappen, 'DDMMYYYY'))
```

For your database tuning, just invoke the merge statement by itself in a SQL tool to try different approaches; then you won't have to worry about killing merges half-way, whicn would be causing a lot of work in the database rolling back transactions, etc.

Update:

OK, I will answer the question instead of providing my solution. :)

You can create a `profile` that is then assigned to a `user` to limit sessions to a specific `CONNECT_TIME` or `IDLE_TIME` or both.  Then if the user exceeds the time, according to http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310

> If a user exceeds the CONNECT_TIME or IDLE_TIME session resource
>   limit, then the database rolls back the current transaction and ends
>   the session. When the user process next issues a call, the database
>   returns an error.

So you can do this:

```
create profile MERGE_PROF limit idle_time 5 connect_time 86400;
alter user BATCH_MERGER_USER profile MERGE_PROF;
```

Then when your session is created, if the session is idle for 5 minutes, Oracle will kill the session, and if it is running solid for 24 hours, (running commands with less than 5 minutes between commands for 24 hours) Oracle will kill the session.

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer! But those tables are already indexed... and i'm not trying to improve the performance (even this solving the problem)... i'm trying to force a connection to be killed... that's the main issue :(

Comment: Updated my answer to answer your question! Oracle recommends using Resource Management instead of profiles, but it is more complex, but here is a reference in case you are interested: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dbrm.htm#CHDDCGGG